# Redirecting to particular page after authentication from views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have three Html pages home.html, destination.html and login.html. 
Home.html has only a button,if I click on this button and if the user is authenticated than he will be redirected to destination.html otherwise to  login.html (I am using builtin login function and that's working properly), When user is logged in the particular username appears on home.html page,but when I click again on button it redirects again to the login.html.

**views.py**
This is views section for home.html and destination.html, I have use builtin function for authentication.

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated



def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate()
        if user is IsAuthenticated:
            return render(request, 'destination.html')
        else:
            return redirect('login/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
def destination(request):
    return render(request, 'destination.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from newapp import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('destination', views.destination, name= 'destination'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html')),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate()
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'destination.html')
        else:
            return redirect('login/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
@login_required
def destination(request):
    return render(request, 'destination.html')
```

Here we are checking user in None or not and then starting a session due to which the data created won't go be available until that particular user is logged in. 
Don't forget to mention `LOGIN_URL="/login/"`in `settings.py`  which will help in preventing users going to destination.html by url manipulation.
It will only be possible if the session is ON.

Comment: Feel free to ask further doubts.

Comment: problem is still there when i click on button it still goes to the login page even user was logged in

Comment: @RanaTalha any further  questions are appreciated

Comment: and try editing your question again, it took me a lot of time to figure it out what you needed.